# Django: add ManyToMany between two apps I cannot modify

Tags: django, django-models

I have two apps:

- `trains` provides the `Train` model, and
- `railroad` the `Rail` model.

Since I totally love trains, I want to ensure that `Train` can only drive over the compatible `Rail`, therefore I implement a `TrainRailCompatibility`. However, I cannot modify neither `Train` nor `Rail` model to add a field `ManyToMany(through=TrainRailCompatibility)` (I am not a maintainer of those apps). I would still like to be able to do in my project something like `my_train.compatible_rails.all()` or `filter(foo__trains__compatible_rails__in=[...])`.

Is there a way / what would be the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couls simply add this class to your desired App

```
class TrailRailCompatibility(models.Model):
    train = models.ForeignKey('app1.Train')
    rail = models.ForeignKey('app2.Rail')
```

and now the `TrailRailCompatibility` - class will be available on both of the referenced models via

```
from app1.models import Train
from app2.models import Rail

Trail.trailrailcompatibility_set.all()
Rail.trailrailcompatibility_set.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is management issue because you can't do something in a proper way. Workaround is ugly and slower because it uses subquery instead of join.

```
class Compatibility(models.Model):
    train = models.ForeignKey('trains.Train', related_name='compatibilities')
    rail = models.ForeignKey('railroad.Rail', related_name='compatibilities')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('train', 'rail')

def get_trains(rails):
    return Train.objects.filter(compatibilities__rail__in=rails)

def get_rails(train):
    return Rail.objects.filter(compatibilities__train_id=train.id)
```

Comment: Note that `Rail.objects.filter(compatibilities__train=train)` will work too but maybe it has additional subquery. Better to check it.

Comment: That could be a solution, thanks. Just wanted to note about the ```__train_id=train```, as you fixed it already while I was typing :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done without adding the `ManyToMany` fields on the `Train` and `Rail` models. You could create a regular `TrainRailCompatibility` model with foreign keys to `Train` and `Rail` and set `unique_together = ('train', 'rail')` and then add entries manually. You just won't be able to access them from the `Train` and `Rail` models.

Comment: It is [possible](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

Comment: @Raz I meant "not possible" in the sense that it's not possible to create a `ManyToMany` relationship in the way Django defines it without access to the 2 models involved.

Comment: Sorry. I missed that you wrote about `ManyToMany `.